# python takes my dictionary is taken for a tuple or a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, callback, tuples

I am trying to develop a personal finance program in python. My expenses are divided into categories, which in turn are divided into subcategories. I am using nested dictinaries to hold this data as shown below:

```
categorias_gastos = {'alimentacao_limpeza':{'almoco':0,
                                            'supermercado':0},
                     'carro': {'combustivel':0,
                               'manutencao':0,
                               'multas_cnh':0},
                     'criaturas_estimacao': {'animais':0,
                                            'plantas':0},
                     'despesas_medicas': {'consultas':0,
                                          'dentista':0,
                                          'exames':0,
                                          'material_permanente':0,
                                          'remedios':0 },
                     'formacao': 0,
                     'impostos': 0,
                     'lazer': 0,
                     'manutencao_casa':0,
                     'seguros':0,
                     'servicos':0,
                     'outros':0}
```

From what I understand, the curly brackets are enough to tell python this is a dicitionary. I then try to access specific data by using nested indexes like categorias_gastos[key1][key2]. The key1 and key2 indexes correspond to the keynames in the expenses categories and subcategories, respectively. This bit of code is,

```
key1 = StringVar()
key1.set('alimentacao_limpeza')

key2 = StringVar()
key1.set('supermercado')
```

This is where the trouble starts as python raises the following attribute error,

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_root'
```

If I instead make the following change

```
#key1 = StringVar()
#key1.set('alimentacao_limpeza')
key1 = 0

#key2 = StringVar()
#key1.set('supermercado')
key2 = 0
```

I can get python to run my code. I try to update the data in the dictionary with by means of a function callback in a button,

```
terminado_button = Button(somar_despesas_frame,
                              text="TERMINADO",
                              font=('arial', 10, 'bold'),
                              command=atualizar_categoria).grid(row=3,
                                                               column=0,
                                                               columnspan=4)
```

The callback function is,

```
def atualizar_categoria():
    global categorias_gastos, despesas, valores
    total_despesas = sum(valores)
    categorias_gastos[key1][key2] = total_despesas
    print("CATEGORIA ATUALIZADA =",categorias_gastos[key1][key2])
```

Another error is then raised:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ridim\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<ipython-input-37-f7d458c1a385>", line 8, in atualizar_categoria
    categorias_gastos[key1][key2] = total_despesas
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

If I make minor changes, python then takes my dictionary for a list and raises a similar error.

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

The full code is presented below:

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# import classes, attributes, and methods of TKinter into current workspace

from tkinter import *
# ttk is Python's binding to the "themed widgets"
from tkinter import ttk

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# global variables

categoria=0

categorias_gastos = {'alimentacao_limpeza':{'almoco':0,
                                            'supermercado':0},
                     'carro': {'combustivel':0,
                               'manutencao':0,
                               'multas_cnh':0},
                     'criaturas_estimacao': {'animais':0,
                                            'plantas':0},
                     'despesas_medicas': {'consultas':0,
                                          'dentista':0,
                                          'exames':0,
                                          'material_permanente':0,
                                          'remedios':0 },
                     'formacao': 0,
                     'impostos': 0,
                     'lazer': 0,
                     'manutencao_casa':0,
                     'seguros':0,
                     'servicos':0,
                     'outros':0}

contador = 0
despesa = 0
despesas = []


#key1 = StringVar()
#key1.set('alimentacao_limpeza')
key1 = 0

#key2 = StringVar()
#key1.set('supermercado')
key2 = 0

valores = []


global categoria, categorias_gastos, contador, despesa, despesas, key1, key2, valores

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# define accountancy calculation functions


def atualizar_categoria():
    global categorias_gastos, despesas, valores
    total_despesas = sum(valores)
    categorias_gastos[key1][key2] = total_despesas
    print("CATEGORIA ATUALIZADA =",categorias_gastos[key1][key2])


def atualizar_despesas():
    global contador,despesa, valores
    valor_despesa = float(despesa.get())
    contador = contador + 1
    filename = ''.join(["Despesa_", str(contador)])
    despesas.append(filename)
    valores.append(valor_despesa)
    print()
    print("ATUALIZAR DESPESAS")
    print(filename," = ",despesa.get())


def exibir_categoria():
    print(categoria.get())

def imprimir_despesa():
    global despesa, despesas, valores
    print("Despesa =",despesa.get())


def selecionar_rubrica():
    global despesa, despesas, key1, key2, valores
    print()
    print("SELECIONAR RUBRICA")
    print("rubrica key1 =", key1)
    print("rubrica key2 =", key2)

    rubricas = ['Supermercado',
                'Almoço']


    selecionar_rubrica_frame = Toplevel(root)
    var = StringVar()
    var.set(rubricas[0])

    # create title label
    Label_1 = Label(selecionar_rubrica_frame,
                    text='SELECIONAR RUBRICA',
                    font=('arial', 12, 'bold')).pack()

    for item in rubricas:
        rubrica = Radiobutton(selecionar_rubrica_frame,
                              text=item,
                              font=('arial', 12, 'bold'),
                              indicatoron=0,
                              variable=var,
                              value=item,
                              command=somar_despesas)

        rubrica.pack(anchor=W,
                     fill=X)


def somar_despesas():
    global despesa, despesas, key1, key2, valores

    print("key1 =", key1)
    print("key2 =", key2)

    despesa = StringVar()
    despesa.set("Inserir valor da despesa")

    # create frame
    somar_despesas_frame=Toplevel(root)

    # create title label
    Label_1 = Label(somar_despesas_frame,
                    text='SOMAR DESPESAS',
                    font=('arial', 12, 'bold')).grid(row=0,
                                                     column=0,
                                                     columnspan=4)

    #create operation label
    despesa_label = Label(somar_despesas_frame,
                          text='Despesa',
                          font=('arial', 10, 'bold')).grid(row=1,column=0)

    #add entry widget to my_frame_1
    despesa_entry = Entry(somar_despesas_frame,
                          textvariable=despesa,
                          font=('arial', 10, 'normal')).grid(row=1,column=1)

    validar_button = Button(somar_despesas_frame,
                            text="Validar",
                            font=('arial', 10, 'bold'),
                            command=atualizar_despesas).grid(row=1,column=3)

    terminado_button = Button(somar_despesas_frame,
                              text="TERMINADO",
                              font=('arial', 10, 'bold'),
                              command=atualizar_categoria).grid(row=3,
                                                               column=0,
                                                               columnspan=4)

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Ia - create the toplevel or root window (an instance of tkinter.class)
root = Tk()
root.geometry('1400x700')
root.title('INSERIR GASTOS')

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CATEGORIAS_GASTOS_FRAME (EXPENDITURE CATEGORIES) AND ITS CONTENTS

# IIa - create categorias_gastos_frame
categorias_gastos_frame = Frame(root,
                                  bd=2,
                                  relief=SUNKEN)

categorias_gastos_frame.pack(side=LEFT,
                               anchor=N)

# add label to to my_frame_1
Label(categorias_gastos_frame,
      text='SELECIONAR CATEGORIA DE GASTOS:',
      font=('arial', 14, 'bold')).pack(anchor=W)


categorias_gastos = [("Alimentação / Limpeza",1), 
                     ("Carro",2),
                     ("Criaturas de Estimação",3),
                     ("Despesas Médicas",4),
                     ("Formação",5),
                     ("Impostos",6),
                     ("Lazer",7),
                     ("Manutenção da Casa",8),
                     ("Seguros",9),
                     ("Serviços",10),
                     ("Outros",11)]

for text, category in categorias_gastos:
        global categoria
        botao = Radiobutton(categorias_gastos_frame,
                            text=text,
                            font=('arial', 12, 'bold'),
                            width=20, 
                            padx=20,
                            indicator=0,
                            variable=key1,
                            value=categoria,
                            command=selecionar_rubrica)

        botao.pack(anchor=W,
                   fill=X)



orientation = Label(categorias_gastos_frame)
orientation.pack(anchor=W,fill=X)

# Ib - the mainloop method is what keeps the root window visible
root.mainloop()
```

I understand the use of global variables is not good and that I should use classes instead. But this is just for me to start learning python.

Thanks very much for any help anyone can provide me with.

Comment: You assigned the object `categorias_gastos` twice in your code.  At the very beginning it was a `dict` but near the end it became a `list` of `tuples`, hence the error.  You want to give your `list` or `dict` two different names.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that looks like a problem: You have defined a global `categorias_gastos` twice.

The second definition will overwrite the first, and it's a list of tuples rather than a dict. Use a different name for your radiobutton tuples, and/or hide it inside (say) a "make_radiobuttons" function.

Comment: Thanks very much to you both who answered my question. Indeed, I didn´t notice I had defined the global categorias_gastos twice. I fixed that and it partially solved the problem.